# Using Sonar Qube to flag "new" issues

Tags: continuous-integration, sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I've just installed SonarQube and it's understandably found a lot of technical debt that we want to eventually fix. However at the moment, I want to make sure that any new code checked in is evaluated and issues flagged in that.

I know I can mark issues as won't fix, but is there a way to flag issues that have arisen after a certain point in time and leave the existing technical debt as "Will fix later"?

I know ideally I'd like to halt development and fix everything right now, but I've only just got buy in for a CI server and some of my senior colleagues don't even see the point of unit tests, let alone ensuring code quality.

Answer (score 2):

SonarQube focuses now on the Leak Period, i.e. problems introduced recently. This is handled through project versions, so you just need to update your string to start a new leak period and immediately differentiate old code from new.

Take a look at [SonarQube itself on SonarQube.com](https://sonarqube.com/overview?id=org.sonarsource.sonarqube%3Asonarqube). The highlighted "Leak Period" section on the right brings attention to problems that are *new in this version*.